# what is %a in python's string formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting

I have a basic question regarding string formatting. I use both python 2.7 and 3+ for my coding

I understand that %s is used for characters or strings

```
name = "John"
print("Hello, %s!" % name)
```

Hello, John!

now, if I use an integer

```
name = 123
print("Hello, %s!" % name)
```

the output is Hello, 123!

And when I do want to convert it to bytes, something like this

```
name = 123
print(b"Hello, %s!" % name)
```

in python 2.7
it throws me an error saying that `%b requires bytes, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'int'`

```
name = 123
print(b"Hello, %a!" % name)
```

Is %a is explicitly used to take the bytes kind of stuff .. I couldn't find much info on %a on web.. and the old code which someone wrote extensively used it and I am debugging that .. SO need some help in understanding the above mentioned (using strings or numbers while converting to bytes )

Comment: See the [documentation for printf style string formatting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting). The difference appears to be that `%s` uses `str()` to perform the conversion, while `%a` uses `ascii()`.

Answer (score 1):

From [PEP 461 -- Adding % formatting to bytes and bytearray](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/):

> `%a` will give the equivalent of `repr(some_obj).encode('ascii', 'backslashreplace')` on the interpolated value. Use cases include developing a new protocol and writing landmarks into the stream; debugging data going into an existing protocol to see if the problem is the protocol itself or bad data; a fall-back for a serialization format; or any situation where defining `__bytes__` would not be appropriate but a readable/informative representation is needed [[6]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/#id15).
>
> `%r` is included as a synonym for `%a` for the sole purpose of making 2/3 code bases easier to maintain. Python 3 only code use `%a` [[7]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0461/#id16).

Answer (score 0):

In the print statement you can replace name by str(name).encode() to eliminate the error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

`%b` is used for formatting a byte value in the print statement.

```
s = "hello"
s_bytes = str.encode(s)
type(s_bytes)
```

class 'bytes'

```
s_bytes
```

b'hello'

```
print(b"The text is %b" % s_bytes)
```

b'The text is hello'

```
print(b"The text is %b" % s)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
TypeError: %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements **bytes**, not 'str'

The bottom line is, you have to pass a byte object when you are formatting with `%b`.

Answer (score 0):

'%a' string format operator. '%a' converts any python object to a string using repr() and then hex-escapes all non-ASCII characters. The '%a' format operator generates the same string as '%r' in Python 2. Also, add '!a' conversion flags to the string.format() method and add '%A' operator to the